# Nvidia settings : does not load the saved X Server Display Configuration (23.04)

Tags: display-resolution, 23.04, nvidia-settings

I am facing an issue with my fresh ubuntu install and the nvidia settings.
I configured my config, to enable 120hz and Gsync.

**I saved the xconf file** but :

When I clic on Quit, (after applying and saving changes), I get this warning message:

"You have pending changes on following page(s):

X Server Display Configuration - Apply,
X Server Display Configuration - Save to X Configuration File

Do you really want to quit?"

this message is pretty curious, as i actually saved my changes, so no pending changes is expected.

Then the X Server configurations are not loaded when I start ubuntu again. A lot af topics are available on the web. none of the answers helped me.

Regards

**Nota**: the X server display config I manually set is the resolution, from "auto" to "3440x1440", that allows me to set the refresh rate to 120Hz.
[120Hz config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSFVQ.png)
Without this, i do not have the 120Hz option, ad the screen appears to be blocked on 60Hz.
[auto config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDrhV.png)

When I restart ubuntu, **the resolution is set on auto again. The rest of the config remains saved actually** (i.e. GSync compatibility)

**Nota2** : I use X11 and not Wayland for gaming purposes. I don't know if there is something related to the issue (i am a newbie)

Nota3: I edited the startup application as follow, with `nvidia-settings --load-config-only`, but without
success:

[startup program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF4iH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Express solution, minutes after my post (hours of researches for nothing :/)

Parameters-> display-> refreshrate.
Gnome overrides the refresh rates on startup ...

voilà !